# Content within Accordion to slide in from the left

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, accordion

i have an accordion but i want the content to slide in from the left after the accordion has come down.

my code so far however this makes the original slide jumpy.

I also have a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y3afuqj5/) showing the original code...

```
 $(function () {
        $(".expand").on("click", function () {
            $(this).next().toggle("slide", {
                direction: "left"

            });

            $expand = $(this).find(">:first-child");

            if ($expand.text() == "\u25B6") {
                $expand.text("\u25BC");

            } else {
                $expand.text("\u25B6");
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: You could use CSS to do the slide action. With CSS animation and you add a class to the content when you want it to start sliding in.

Comment: For sliding from the sides, you will have to use jQueryUI, jQuery by default just have SlideUp and SlideDown effects

Comment: so I've added a class however this messes with my original slidetoggle :/ http://jsfiddle.net/y3afuqj5/2/

Comment: sorry this version http://jsfiddle.net/y3afuqj5/3/

Answer (score 0):

Try this fiddle.

```
$(".expand").on("click", function () {
    $('.detail').toggle('slide');
})
```